# Converting a char* to a UNICODE_STRING in kernel

Tags: c, windows, types, type-conversion, kernel

I try to find the address of a given import using the MMGetSystemRoutineAddress function.
The only problem is that this function takes a pointer to a UNICODE_STRING and my import name variable has the type char*.

To convert it to a UNICODE_STRING I tried using the function RtlInitUnicodeString.
The problem here is that this function takes a PCWSTR and as I read that it is not possible to use a non const value for this.
This is my code:

```
DbgPrint("%s", image_import_by_name->Name); // >> outputs "DbgPrintEx"
                
UNICODE_STRING routineNameByInput;
RtlInitUnicodeString(&routineNameByInput, L"DbgPrintEx");

UNICODE_STRING routineNameByVar;
RtlInitUnicodeString(&routineNameByVar, (PUNICODE_STRING)&image_import_by_name->Name);

DbgPrint("%wZ", routineNameByInput); // >> outputs "DbgPrintEx"
DbgPrint("%wZ", routineNameByVar); // >> outputs "???"
                 
MmGetSystemRoutineAddress(&routineNameByInput); // >> works perfectly
MmGetSystemRoutineAddress(&routineNameByInput); // >> bluescreens
MmGetSystemRoutineAddress((PUNICODE_STRING)&image_import_by_name->Name); // >> bluescreens
```

I also tried recreating the UNICODE_STRING by zero terminating the importname but nothing worked.

Is there not some easy way to convert a char* to a UNICODE_STRING?

Why does RtlInitUnicodeString even take a PCWSTR in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search `windows ansi to unicode kernel mode` reveals [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-rtlansistringtounicodestring)

> **RtlAnsiStringToUnicodeString function (wdm.h)**
>
> RtlAnsiStringToUnicodeString converts the given ANSI source string into a Unicode string.

Definition:

```
NTSYSAPI NTSTATUS RtlAnsiStringToUnicodeString(
  [in, out] PUNICODE_STRING DestinationString,
  [in]      PCANSI_STRING   SourceString,
  [in]      BOOLEAN         AllocateDestinationString
);
```

Sounds like that's exactly what you want.

> Why does RtlInitUnicodeString even take a PCWSTR in the first place?

Becuase a UNICODE STRING is a struct, not a buffer.

```
typedef struct _UNICODE_STRING {
  USHORT Length;
  USHORT MaximumLength;
  PWSTR  Buffer;
} UNICODE_STRING, *PUNICODE_STRING;
```

The kernel passes around instances of UNICODE_STRING with the the trio of `{length, capacity, ptr}` probably to avoid unnecessary wcslen/strlen scans on a string. And it makes string append operations faster.  They provide the helper function, `RtInitUnicodeString` to convert a PWCSTR (const wchar_t*) to properly initilize an instance of UNICODE_STRING. A similar deal exists for ANSI_STRING as well.

So if you have an instance of a char* string, you'd probably do something like this:

```
ANSI_STRING astr = {0};
UNICODE_STRING ustr = {0};
PVOID addr = NULL;

RtlInitAnsiString(&astr, image_import_by_name.Name);  // assumes Name is char*
RtlAnsiStringToUnicodeString(&ustr, &astr, TRUE);
addr = MmGetSystemRoutineAddress(&ustr);
RtlFreeUnicodeString(&ustr);
```